# Wordpress Gravity forms get field id by label name

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to get a field ID based on a field label name, versus hard coding the values.

I can retrieve the form ID given the form name

```
RGFormsModel::get_form_id($post_title);
```

Then use the retrieve all fields and much more based on the ID.

```
RGFormsModel::get_form_meta($id);
```

However, parsing through the returned values is very clunky.

Reading through the api, it doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to retrieve the field ID based on its label name.

Is there something in the API or a solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you aren't missing anything. If you want to get a field object by it's label, you'll have to loop through the form object fields property and compare the desired label with that of each field until you find it.

```
function gw_get_field_by_label( $label ) {
    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if( $field->label == 'My Field Label' ) {
            return $field;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could use it like so:

```
$field = gw_get_field_by_label( 'My Field Label' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping there was some more built in way to do this. Certainly it feels more like we're brute forcing it. Another way I thought of is to query the db directly.